# How to pray if Friday prayers are cancelled?

Tags: jumuah, khutbah

Assalam walaikum Due to spread of recent panademic the authorities have closed mosques in Kuwait. Everyone is asked to pray at home. My question is how many Rakats do I pray for Jummah? Or we have to continue praying only dhuhar as there is no Khutbah.

Answer (score 2):

Note that to pray a congregation prayer you need at least two people who ar mukallaf (reached at least the ade of puberty and have no mental sickness etc.).
For jumuah prayer these two people should further be male.
This would be the minimum requirement however most scholars would require a bigger gathering as jumuah in the early days was performed in only one mosque so all the people of a town or city would gather in this one location (some said 3 including the imam, others 13 including the imam others spoke of 40 or more people). Further most scholars even require settlement so a jumuah on a road trip or in a rural area is not necessary. But most of these requirements can be refuted somehow.
One crucial condition is that it must be prayed in a mosque or better masjid, a place specified for performing the prayers (I couldn't find a fatwa allowing to pray  jumuah at home or in a place that can't be called masjid in the widest definition of the meaning). Some scholars however insisted on a built mosque.

So assuming you have found at least  two male adults and adequate place one of these men should call for jumuah and another should prepare a small khutba (strictly speaking two as there's a small pause between two khutba parts) or consider reading/reciting surat qaf in the first khutba in worst case.
After finishing the second khutba and du'a they would pray after iqamah.

If you can't meet this minimum requirement you should pray dhor (4 raka'a) instead.

Finally note that the explanation above is about how to pray jumuah if a mosque is not open or reachable. In case that the prayer was canceled by a Muslim authority due to given circumstances it is better avoiding it and leave the judgement for these people (if they done wrong) to Allah. However you could still pray the five daily prayers in congregation with both females or males in your house.

Comment: There are many more requirements for leading Jummah. For one, you need to given permission by a sultan (since there is no sultan in most states these days, this duty is typically delegated to the Muslim with the highest position in the state). Just read Zuhr, as you're excused with the current scenario.

Comment: Also Jummah needs to be prayed in a mastjid.

Comment: @moinudin The agreement of a sultan is not necessary (in general) it is rather necessary for canceling the prayers. A sultan who disagrees would be a big sinner or regarded as kafir and people are free to go against him. If one prayes at home one mostly is free to do whatever one wants to do. But if we believe that jumuah requires a masjid it is rather impossible to pray it at home.

Answer (score 1):

You can pray only Zuhr prayer with 4 faraz if you want to pray at home, and Jummah prayer cannot be prayed at home. So instead of 2 Faraz of Jummah, you'll need to pray 4 Faraz of Zuhr.

Answer (score 1):

The condition for Jummah prayer is that it needs to be done in the public and we cannot perform it alone or secretly. As a result, if you are praying at home, you simply cannot perform Jummah prayer, rather you have to pray Duhr prayer as usual. Jazakallahu Khairun!

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever came late and missed Jummah? You would have instead prayed Dhuhr 4 Raka!

If there is no Jummah or you missed Jummah, the ruling is exactly the same!

Comment: This example has an issue in the Hanafi maddhab one would pray only two raka'as if one came late to the Friday prayer and didn't catch up a raka'a.